# read large CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

So, I have a large CSV file (Name_data_all.txt) with about 2.4 million names in it formatted like this:

```
,,Roughdawg4,xLukk,blackangel887462,Semnas,HUTCHY007,MrUnknown625,maxijodi,jeromepotel
```

However, the way the data was inserted into the CSV file, it's all on one continuous line

What I need to do is insert them all into a database table but the problem is that when I try and read in the file I get this error:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
```

Now I know I can use fseek() and fgets(); but I cannot figure out how to do so, I was thinking of just partially extracting data, inserting, and then grabbing next chunk and so on...

I know this form of extraction works and outputs each name into unique array indexes but again, memory problems if I do more than ~600k:

```
$handle = fopen("Name_data_all.txt", "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 6000000, ",");
$pos1 = fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: dont use php at all mysql has a function for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Are there any line breaks at all in that file? If not, then don't try to read it as a csv; just read fixed-size blocks

Comment: If it's just one continuous stream of comma separated values, read and parse it in chunks.

Comment: Also consider breaking your input file into smaller chunks, assuming you have access to an editor that can cope with that much file

Comment: Are you sure it's one line, and not just a different line ending than you're expecting?